# osicat-posix:stat freeze

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop, sbcl

I'm quite new to Common Lisp and would require help in using the functions in the "osicat" system. What I am trying to accomplish is to get the size of a file. To accomplish this, I would like to use the result returned by the function "stat" of the osicat system. Upon trying to get information from a file that is found in the same directory where I launched sbcl from, it seems as if either the function is taking forever to collect information from the file or it either does nothing and hangs for an unknown reason. I'm not quite how to go about this and I have no clue what might be causing this issue.

Here is the sequence of actions undertaken until I encounter the issue:

1. Open Powershell.
2. Execute cygwin
3. Execute sbcl
4. (ql:quickload :osicat) (which is loaded without any complaints)
5. (in-package :osicat-posix)
6. (osicat-posix:stat "env.db")

After executing the last command, it is as though the repl loop hangs. I tried scouring the internet for any clues or answers as to why this might happen, but only found tutorials giving the same instructions that are giving me a hard time. Any insight, clues, hints or help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe with https://github.com/ruricolist/trivial-file-size?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your sequence of actions and you should expect a result you wanted. Here is the output for me in SLIME:

```
CL-USER> (osicat-posix:stat "/etc/passwd")
#<OSICAT-POSIX:STAT {1039159BB3}>
CL-USER> (describe (osicat-posix:stat "/etc/passwd"))
#<OSICAT-POSIX:STAT {103916B4F3}>
  [standard-object]

Slots with :INSTANCE allocation:
  DEV                            = 64769
  INO                            = 25166054
  MODE                           = 33188
  NLINK                          = 1
  UID                            = 0
  GID                            = 0
  RDEV                           = 0
  SIZE                           = 2324
  BLKSIZE                        = 4096
  BLOCKS                         = 8
  ATIME                          = 1576246741
  MTIME                          = 1575707407
  CTIME                          = 1575707407
```

Maybe, your problem is connected with `cygwin` interaction. You might get some clues on what's happening by running `sbcl` under `strace`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try without using cygwin.